# am i required to create a run/debug config to do basic debugging in Pycharm

Tags: debugging, pycharm

do i have to actively create a run/debug config in order to debug a simple python script? its not clear to me what specifically I am going to add to this configuration.    I have tried to follow along the jetbrains tutorial for "debugging your first program" and the debugger is not behaving or looking like the tutorial example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its not clear to me what specifically I am going to add to this configuration.

To add a configuration

- Go to `Run`->`Edit Configuration`

  - [image]
- Click on `Add New Configuration`

  - [image]
- Select the script you want to run

  - [image]
- Then click apply, and now you can run it.

To debug, just click on the line you want to stop the debugger

- [image]
- Then use `step-over` your line or `step-into` your method.

  - [image]

Comment: thanks. is it true that a config gets created automatically? i added a new file test.py to my project and was able to debug it without manually creating a config file.  HOWEVER.. the path to the config file seems to be a path to a folder called scratches that is not where I created the test.py.   what is happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the configs are created automatically or not.

Comment: If you start debug via right-click while being in test.py, then yes, run configuration is created automatically